# Maven can't find artefact from Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

We have an Atlassian Bamboo instance building and deploying our projects (snapshots) to Nexus, around 11:20 pm every day.

Another Bamboo instance runs a test plan A at midnight and fails because it can't find an artefact from Nexus (although it's looking in the right repositories), artefact that was built by the other Bamboo instance and is actually in Nexus.

A test plan B starts around 00:30 on the same instance and this one finds the artefact. In the morning, when I manually launch the plan A, it works well.

So I suspect a cache/metadata issue, but I couldn't figure out what is the right configuration to set, either in Nexus or in the Maven settings.

It's running Maven 2.2.1. Other plans running Maven 3.0.5 for a different version of our project don't seem to have the problem. Nexus is 2.7.2-03.
The error is "2 required artifacts are missing." and the list of Nexus groups in "from the specified remote repositories:" is the right one. Those groups are configured like that in the project's pom:

```
<snapshots>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
</snapshots>
```

Any idea about how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Try to run your build with debug option (-X) to see URLs maven uses to download artifacts, then figure out either URLs are right and if they are why Nexus doesn't return artifacts right away.

Comment: Try to run 'Refresh metadata' maintenance job on nexus between deploy and next build and see if it would solve the issue.

Comment: Using the same artifact repo for both Maven 2 and Maven 3 snapshot builds can be a problem.  Maven 3 requires timestamped snapshots and Maven 2 does not.  We had similar issues when a project was built with Maven 2, someone new to the team didn't realize that, installed Maven 3 on their machines, and deployed snapshots to the remote repo.  Builds were no longer correct for the Maven 2 folks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The URLs shown are correct, I'll enable the job. About mixing Maven2/Maven3 artefacts, I had no idea it could lead to some problems, I'll see if separating them fixes the issue as well. Thank you !

Comment: I agree with user944849 ... you should be using the same Maven version and definitely NOT mix Maven 2 and Maven 3.

Comment: I've switch all automated builds in Bamboo from Maven 2 to Maven 3 and it seems it has fixed the issue, thank you. However, I can't find how I can accept user944849's answer.

Comment: At least you could do a upvote for his (@user944849) comment :)

Comment: Since my comment turned out to be helpful I added more detail as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices we've identified for moving Maven 2 builds to Maven 3:

1) All of the builders (individual users running builds on personal machines plus Jenkins/CI) should be converted at the same time. In other words, once the POM for an artifact has been adjusted as needed and the built artifact deployed to the remote repository with Maven 3, then **Maven 2 should not be used to build that same artifact ever again**. This is because Maven 3 uses timestamped snapshots, while Maven 2 does not. Also, Maven 2 and Maven 3 handle dependency resolution and repository metadata differently. Mixing the two doesn't work well.

One symptom is someone commits changes, builds, and deploys to the remote repo with Maven 3, then another developer tries to download the changed jar with Maven 2 and gets the old one.  The team may prevent the artifacts from being built with Maven 2 using the Enforcer plugin.

2) All builders should clean out their local artifact repositories.  Maven 2 and Maven 3 handle dependency resolution and repository metadata differently, and a fresh repository insulates the developer from strange, hard to find problems. (Since Maven will then have to download the world on the first build, consider doing the first Maven 3 build before you go to lunch or leave work for the day.)

3) Someone with delete privileges on the remote repository (e.g. Nexus, Artifactory) should log into the remote repo, find the artifact(s) in the Snapshots repository and delete the snapshot version during which the Maven 2 to 3 migration occurred.

For example, say that the team is working on 2.0-SNAPSHOT, and there's a task to move from Maven 2 to 3 for this version. When the POM changes for the task are complete, the developer logs into the remote repo, finds `com.company.some-group:myArtifact(s)`, and removes the 2.0-SNAPSHOT version entirely. This will remove all snapshots built by Maven 2.